# OCIDefineByPos() with OCINumbers

Tags: c++, oracle-call-interface

I'm developing C++ application with OCI. I need to fetch data from the DB in to OCINumber. I'm confused on how to use the function OCIDefineByPos() with OCINumbers.
Can someone help me with this.

Given below is the part of the code where I call OCIDefineByPos function. 
pStmt is a OCIStmt* and p_Error is OCIError*. Following function pointers are used.

```
1. pf_OCINumberFromReal = function pointer to OCINumberFromReal
2. pf_OCINumberToReal  = function pointer to OCINumberToReal
3. pf_DefineByPos = function pointer to OCIDefineByPos.

OCINumber ocinTest;
long double dnum = 0.0;

(*pf_OCINumberFromReal)(p_Error, &dnum, sizeof(dnum), &ocinTest);
int iLength1 = sizeof(ocinTest);


OCIDefine* pDfn = NULL;
iRet = (*pf_DefineByPos)(pStmt, &pDfn, p_Error, 1, (dvoid *) &ocinTest,
    (sword) iLength1, SQLT_NUM, (dvoid *) 0, (ub2 *)0,
        (ub2 *)0, OCI_DEFAULT);
if (iRet == OCI_SUCCESS)
{
    (*pf_OCINumberToReal)(p_Error, &ocinTest, sizeof(dnum), &dnum);
    std::cout <<std::fixed << std::setprecision (10) << dnum << std::endl;
}
```

although iRet = OCI_SUCCESS it didn't fetch the value in the db correctly.(Value of the sql query defined using pStmt). dnum is 0.0 even after the call. This pf_DefineByPos is working fine for other data types such as int ,double etc.

So can someone help me to find the issue with this.

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried, were in particular is your problem / confusion?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci12oty.htm#i423538

Comment: I edited my original post with the code I'm using and the exact problem. Please help me on that as this is bit urgent issue that i need to fix. @Torsten: I already read that article. But it doesn't describe how to use OCINumbers with OCIDefineByPos.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not completely taken out of context, then your missing several essential pieces.

A typical OCI program involves the following steps:

1. Prepare an SQL statement (OCIStmtPrepare)
2. Bind the result columns or output parameters to the variables that will receive the result values (OCIDefineByPos)
3. Execute the statement (OCIStmtExecute)
4. Do something with the result

It seems to me that you're skipping step 3 and expect some result right after step 2. But step 2 doesn't fetch any data. It just creates an association between the query result and your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `DefineByPos` for `OCINumber` with `SQLT_VNU` type rather than `SQLT_NUM`.